# update html page using AJAX and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I have 3 divs in my html page which has display:none by default, I want to check with DB on regular basis and update my display attribute of divs accordingly.

```
<div class="gunnybag" style="float:right">
        <div id="p1" style="display:none;"><img id="drag1"  draggable="true" src="coconut.png"></div>
        <div id="p2" style="display:none;"><img id="drag2"  draggable="true" src="coconut.png"></div>
        <div id="p3" style="display:none;"><img id="drag3"  draggable="true" src="coconut.png"></div>
    </div>
```

For this I have written this JS file,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     doAjax();
    });

function doAjax(){
$.ajax({
    url: "db_fetch.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
        var dataArray = JSON.decode(json);
        dataArray.each(function(entry){
            var i=1;
            if(entry.valueName==true){        //checking if `state`= true/false.
                $q('#p'+i).css( "display","block" );
            }
            else{
                $q('#p'+i).css( "display","none" );
            }
            i=i++;
        })
    }

}).complete(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){doAjax();}, 1000);  // check with DB every sec
    });
}
```

Here is the db_fetch.php

```
<?php
try{
  $con=mysql_connect("sqlservername","uname", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e;
}
mysql_select_db("db_name", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$q = mysql_query("SELECT `state` FROM `table` ");   //selecting all `state` from table
var_dump($q);
$query = mysql_query($q, $con);
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo json_encode($results);    //returns json obj to above JS

?>
```

my DB has 2 columns id and state, id has p1,p2,p3 as values, and state is either true or false.

Kindly point out what is it that im doing wrong.

Your response is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you giving single qoutes on your table name in select query?

Comment: They are supposed to be backquotes -> ` ... both, table name and column name

Comment: Yes true you should not instead use `` operator for both table and column name

Comment: I belive the $q('p'+i) should be $q('#p'+i) your searching for tag with id not tag p1,p2, further using 'div#p'+i should cut down on dom searches in theory

Comment: @drk:thanks for pointing that out,changed it.. but still not working, http://www.nagendra.0fees.net/cng.html is the link btw, as per current DB states, 1st div should be display:block. But its still display:none.

Comment: I think the way you attach the ajax to on load might have issue there is no requests to your php backand - window.onLoad = doAjax, if you use jQuery then use their notion of attaching $(document).ready(handler) - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @drk thanks alot, changed window.onLoad = doAjax; TO  $(document).ready(function() {
 doAjax();
});   But now getting response as <resource(3) of type (mysql result)
null> from db_fetch.

Comment: @drk the error is now with the db_fetch.php, its returning NULL as json.

Comment: @drk After db_fetch.php which is retuning NULL, this is what i'm getting, on firebug, TypeError: JSON.decode is not a function 
var dataArray = JSON.decode(json); Its on http://www.nagendra.0fees.net/cng.html you can check.

Comment: @Rao Add print_r($results); in db_fetch.php and see its output.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.onload function like this.

```
<script language="javascript">
 window.onload = function() {

  doAjax();

 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code. Problem was I was parsing json,
NOTE: if you are using dataType: "json", in $.ajax() then YOU DONT NEED TO PARSE THE JSON, Its ALREADY PARSED!

ajx.js:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
 doAjax();
});

function doAjax(){
var i=0;
$.ajax({
    url: "db_fetch.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){

        jQuery.each(json, function(i){

            if(json[i].data.state=='true'){
                $('#p'+(i+1)).css( "display","block" );
            }
            else{
                $('#p'+(i+1)).css( "display","none" );
            }
            i=i++;
        });
    }

}).complete(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){doAjax();}, 2000);
    });
}
```